# how to remove the pager fragment from activity to prevent the old fragment instance to be restored by os

Tags: kotlin, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

It is an activity hosting a pager fragment which has  `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` and the adapter class derived from `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

The problem is from the pager fragment it has two or three fragments cached, but the data is not parseable (including a view dynamically getting from a 3rd part sdk), when sometime os recreate this fragment in case like minimize/reopen it, or after rotation  the  restored fragment are blank (using the one from cache and lacking data).

Not find a way to re-populate the fragments restored by os through the pager fragment's recreation flow.

Even tried in the pager fragment to clear the adapter's data in onActivityCreated()

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        val childFragmentManager = childFragmentManager
        mAdapter = ContentPagerAdapter( activity as Context, 
                         childFragmentManager, emptyList()) 
        mContentViewPager!!.setAdapter(mAdapter)
        mAdapter?.setData(emptyList())
    }
```

the adapter:

```
fun setData(itemsList: List<Data>) {
    this.data = itemsList
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

the viewPager seems still showing the previous cachhed fragment without expected data after the re-creation flow is complete.  (tried to make sure it is from the cached one, by in the fragment's `onsaveInstance()`  to save the position of the data in the adapter data list, and the re-created fragment in the viewPager got that position, so it is a os re-created one from cache.  But how could it be after at beging already set the adapter with empty list at `onActivityCreated()`).

Cannt resolve with clean the fragments by setting data to empty.

So tried to remove the page fragment from the activity at `onDestroy()` with hope that there will be no fragment to be put in cache:

```
class ContentPagerFragment :Fragment {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_pager, container, false)
        mContentViewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.contentViewPager)

        return view
     }


    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        val childFragmentManager = childFragmentManager
        mAdapter = ContentPagerAdapter( activity as Context, 
                         childFragmentManager, emptyList()) 
        mContentViewPager!!.setAdapter(mAdapter)
        mAdapter?.setData(emptyList())
    }

    interface RemoveFragmentAtClose {
        fun onContentPagerFragmentDoestroy()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        (activity as? RemoveAtCloseFragment)?
            .onContentPagerFragmentDoestroy()
        super.onDestroy()
    }

}
```

and in the hosting activity

```
class HostActivity : AppCompatActivity(), 
                     ContentPagerFragment.RemoveFragmentAtClose {

    override fun onContentPagerFragmentDoestroy() {
                 supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().
        remove(supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.pagerFragmentContainer))
            .commitAllowingStateLoss()

        var contentPagerFragment = ContentPagerFragment::class.java.cast(supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.pagerFragmentContainer))

        Log.i(TAG, " onContentPagerFragmentDoestroy(), this $this" +
            "\ngetContentPagerFragment: $contentPagerFragment"
        )
    }

    override fun onAttachFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        Log.d(TAG, " onAttachFragment(), " +
            "fragment: $fragment \nthis $this")
    }

}
```

But the log shows that the `supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.pagerFragmentContainer)` still find the fragment after the `.commitAllowingStateLoss()` call.

And when os restores the activity the ContentPagerFragment is showing up in the activity's `onAttachFragment(fragment: Fragment)`  before activity's `onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)`  is called.

Why is the viewPager using the old fragment after remove the pager fragment from the activity's supportFragmentManager?

How to prevent the view pager from use the cached fragment?

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to solve this?